# остановить все потоки при паузе одной функции

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность

Добрый день. есть скрипт, он запускает в 5 потоков одну и ту же функцию, при помощи threading. Функция при определенных условиях ставится на паузу time.sleep. НО! остальные 4 потока продолжают работать. как сделать так, чтобы на паузу вставали все 5 потоков?

Comment: Можно сделать общую переменную и в каждом потоке её проверять. Можно отправлять какой-то параметр потокам через [очередь](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/queue.html).

Comment: @sergey-gornostaev тоже уже подумал про общую переменную, так наверно будет проще, спасибо!

Comment: семафор это называется.)
смотри модули threading.Lock

Comment: А мне кажется для этой темы ближе https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#condition-objects хоть с моей колокольни он устроен несколько странновато.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы останавливать итерации в функции при каждом срабатывании условия в любом из потоков на 5 секунд (для каждого срабатывания):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3 
"""Stop all threads for 5 seconds if some condition happens."""
import random
import threading
import time

def safe_write(s, lock=threading.Lock()):
    with lock:
        print(s, end="", flush=True)

def worker(char, started: threading.Event, lock=threading.Lock()):
    while started.wait():
        safe_write(char)  # do some work
        if random.random() < .025:  # if some condition
            # pause for 5 seconds
            with lock:  # the pauses are consecutive if the condition
                # triggers in more than one thread
                started.clear()  # this stops cycles in all threads
                try:
                    safe_write(" wait")
                    for c in ".....":
                        safe_write(c)
                        time.sleep(1)
                    safe_write("continue\n")
                finally:
                    started.set()  # start the cycles again
        else:
            time.sleep(.1)

started = threading.Event()
for char in "12345":
    threading.Thread(target=worker, args=[char, started], daemon=True).start()

print("Press Enter to exit", flush=True)
started.set()  # start all cycles
input()
```

Это можно реализовать, используя более примитивный объект, такой как `threading.Condition()`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3 -u
"""Stop all threads for 5 seconds if some condition happens."""
import random
import threading
import time

def worker(char, cv=threading.Condition()):
    can_run = True
    while True:
        safe_write(char)  # do some work
        if random.random() < .025:  # if some condition
            # pause for 5 seconds
            with cv:  # the pauses are consecutive if the condition triggers in more than one thread
                can_run = False  # this stop cycles in all threads
                try:
                    safe_write(" wait V seconds")
                    for c in ".....":
                        safe_write(c)
                        time.sleep(1)
                    safe_write("continue\n")
                finally:
                    can_run = True  # start the cycles again
                    cv.notify_all()
        else:
            time.sleep(.1)
            with cv:  # wait until we can run
                while not can_run:
                    cv.wait()

print("Press Enter to exit", flush=True)
for char in "12345":
    threading.Thread(target=worker, args=[char], daemon=True).start()
input()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lock=threading.Lock()
```

in threads:

```
lock.acquire()
time.sleep(5)
lock.release()
```

Comment: А можете показать пример использования? Чтобы можно было запустить и увидеть

Comment: кст, ваш пример можно упростить через with-выражение: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#using-locks-conditions-and-semaphores-in-the-with-statement

Answer (score 0):

```
import threading
from datetime import datetime
import time

def job(p):
   global lock
   lock.acquire()
   for i in range(0,5):
      print p, datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S'), threading.currentThread().getName()
      time.sleep(1)
   lock.release()

lock=threading.Lock()
for i in range(0,3):
   t=threading.Thread(target=job, args=(i,))
   t.start()
t.join()
```

Comment: `global lock` зачем тут нужен `global`?

Comment: у вас функция строго последовательно выполняется.

Comment: Правильно, потому что у каждого потока в примере есть пауза. Конечно эта пауза должна вызываться условно. Я просто показал как использовать object Lock

Comment: Одного lock для задачи мало. Посмотрите на код в моём ответе. Если думаете, что достаточно, то продемонстрируйте как все потоки останавливать [на время] одновременно при срабатывании условия в каком-то одном потоке.