# Python функции и потоки

Tags: python, многопоточность

Есть цикл, который запускает цикл, который запускает функцию 5 потоками. Цикл `while` ищет на странице сслыки (их всегда 50), затем цикл `for` передаёт их в функцию 5 потоками с разными параметрами. Всё прекрасно работает пока `while`  не переходит на следующую итерацию. Дебагер показывает что цикл `for`  создаёт ещё 5 потоков в то время как предидущие не закончились, и так с каждой итерацией `while`.
Как сделать так чтобы цикл `for` "ждал" пока одна функция законит работу, а потом запускал бы следующую? Или если это будет проще, то "ждал" бы пока все потоки закончат работу, а потом запускал следующие 5.

```
    while j < members_quantity:
        url_count = (url + "&offset=" + str(j))
        count_data = session.get(url_count, headers=headers)
        member_link = re.findall(r"href=\"/(\S+)\" class=\"inline_item", count_data.text)
        for i in range(0, len(member_link), 10):
            th = Thread(target=parser, args=(login_list[int(i / 10)], password_list[int(i / 10)], member_link[i:i + 10]))
            th.start()
        j += 50
```

[остановить все потоки при паузе одной функции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/716675) уже смотрел, не подходит.

Comment: Не проще ли использовать multiprocessing.Pool и не мучиться? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно вот так подождать, пока созданная пачка тредов завершится.

```
threads = [] # храним потоки в списке
for i in range(0, len(member_link), 10):
    th = Thread(target=parser, args=(login_list[int(i / 10)], password_list[int(i / 10)], member_link[i:i + 10]))
    th.start()
    threads.append(th) # добавляем поток в список

for th in threads: # проходим по сохранённым потокам
    th.join() # ждём завершения потока
```

Вообще не лучший шаблон работы с потоками, у вас получится периодически будет работать всего один поток, самый долгий, когда остальные уже будут завершены.

Лучше сделать нормальную очередь и разгребать её через `multiprocessing.Pool`.

А ещё лучше использовать `asyncio`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и комментарии к коду. Я только начал изучать потоки.  Ваш код работает, но да - как говорил Риддик: " будем бежать с одной скоростью- с моей". Самый долгий поток заметно снижает производительность. Буду изучать мультипроцессинг.

Comment: Мультипроцессинг не даст тут прироста скорости. Get выполняется паралельно в потоках

Comment: Очередь не нужна для пула, там есть imap